# Types are deprecated in percolate queries but PercolateQueryBuilder class still requires the type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

I have been receiving warning messages each time my app does percolate. I'm using the 7.4.0 versions of elasticsearch and percolate clients. Elasticsearch is also at 7.4.0 version. I know types are deprecated at 7th version, but `PercolateQueryBuilder` class is still requiring `indexedDocumentType`. I have checked other constructors, but it doesn't offer a constructor to build percolate query without a type.

Warning message:

> request [POST
>   http://localhost:9200/saved_searches/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&scroll=1m&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true]
>   returned 1 warnings: [299
>   Elasticsearch-7.4.0-22e1767283e61a198cb4db791ea66e3f11ab9910 "[types
>   removal] Types are deprecated in [percolate] queries. The [type] of
>   the indexed document should no longer be specified."]

Code to run percolating job.

```
PercolateQueryBuilder percolateQuery = new PercolateQueryBuilder("query",
        "order", "_doc", order.getId(),
        null,
        null,
        null);
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("saved_search");
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource()
                    .storedFields(Collections.emptyList())
                    .query(constantScoreQuery(percolateQuery));
searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I can't find what I have done wrong.